# как получить передаваемый аргумент в методе start

Tags: javafx

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    // аргументы из main?
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Когда файл открывается с помощью какой-то программы, путь к файлу передается через параметры командной строки (в методе `start` пишем `Application.Parameters params = getParameters()`, берем первый полученный параметр, [вот тут пример](https://metanit.com/java/javafx/1.3.php)). Чтобы поменять ассоциации файла (будем считать что под Windows), правой кнопкой по mp3 файлу - свойства - приложение - изменить - указать свою программу.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо

Comment: @insolor столкнулся с проблемой при множественном выборе в виндовс. Каждый выбранный файл открывает свое собственное окно приложения

Comment: Тогда приложение должно проверять, был ли запущен экземпляр данного приложения, и если уже было запущено - передавать в "исходный" экземпляр приложения "сигнал", что нужно открыть еще такой-то файл.

Comment: @insolor некогда не проверял что то на верхнем уровне в точке входа так что представления не имею как это сделать я самоучка если можешь дать ссылку на какой то ресурс где есть подобная информация был бы признателен

Comment: Вообще это сложный (составной) вопрос, лучше его задать отдельно.

Comment: @insolor уже сделал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/как-сделать-stage-единственным-экземпляром-а-из-последующих-запусков-взять-тольк

Comment: @ спасибо за помощь хоть с getParameters() разабрался