# Открытие нескольких файлов из проводника в одном экземпляре приложения

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим, тип файла txt ассоциирован с нашим приложением. При выборе нескольких файлов в проводнике и нажатии Enter открывается столько экземпляров приложения, сколько было выбрано файлов, в каждый экземпляр параметром передается путь к одному из выбранных файлов.

Нужно чтобы при открытии нескольких файлов из проводника все файлы "открылись" (были добавлены в список) в одном экземпляре приложения.

Результат сейчас:

[image: результат сейчас]

Нужен вот такой результат:

[image: нужно вот так]

мой код

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    Application.Parameters parameters = getParameters();
    List<String> list = parameters.getUnnamed();
    for (String s : list) {
        textArea.setText(s);
    }
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().add(textArea);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95320/discussion-on-question-by-armen-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должна выглядеть реализация через сокеты. Приложение пытается подключить сокет к порту 9000 (он может быть любым) на локальном хосте (собственно, ваш компьютер). Если ему удаётся это сделать, то оно отправляет на этот порт параметры, если же не удаётся, это значит, что сервер на этот порт ещё не создан, значит, приложение открывается в первый раз, тогда создаётся сервер на этот порт в отдельном потоке, который ждёт, когда ему пришлют параметры. Когда к порту присоединятся какой-то сокет, он открывает новый поток, имеющий ссылку на первоначальный экземпляр класса, который принимает параметры и отправляет их на этот самый экземпляр, то есть, в открытое уже приложение.

```java
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Main main = this;
    Parameters parameters = getParameters();
    try(Socket socket = new Socket()) {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",9000),2000/*если за две секунды не устанавливается связь, выбрасывается ConnectException*/);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        for (String unnamed : parameters.getUnnamed())
            writer.write(unnamed + " ");
        writer.flush();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (ConnectException exception) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
        new Service<>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Object> createTask() {
                return new Task<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() {
                        while(true) {
                            try {
                                new MyServer(serverSocket.accept(),main).start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }.start();
    }
    Pane root = new Pane();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Open Files");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void sendParameters(LinkedList<String> listOfParams) {
    //код, обрабатывающий параметры
}

class MyServer extends Service {
    Socket socket;
    Main application;

    MyServer(Socket socket, Main application) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() {
                try {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    LinkedList<String> listOfParams = new LinkedList<>();
                    while(scanner.hasNext())
                        listOfParams.add(scanner.next());
                    application.sendParameters(listOfParams);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: это ответ к какому вопросу?

Comment: Это насчёт использования сокета для решения проблемы. Мы тут обсуждали уже просто.

Comment: @Armen ладно, раз мы на ты. Ты же можешь в ответ на мой вопрос это написать.

Comment: Не помешал бы пример, как из сервера добавлять полученные данные в text area.

Comment: В методе `sendParameters()` можно добавить строки из переданного в него списка в text area.

Comment: Это, просто, настолько элементарно, что бессмысленно показывать.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, я вот например только изучаю Java - мне совсем не очевидно. По предыдущему опыту программирования я предполагаю, что GUI и MyServer работают в разных потоках, и данные между ними нужно передавать через очередь, пайп, или что там в Java есть. Могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: @insolor в теле класса создаётся `TextArea textArea = new TextArea();`, в методе `start()` добавляется на панель `root.getChildren().add(textArea);`, в методе `sendParameters(LinkedList<String> listOfParams)` пишется `listOfParams.forEach(s -> textArea.appendText(s + " "));`. Насчёт передачи данных между потоками, я в это не углублялся, есть дополнительные классы для этого, такие как `Pipe` и `Exchanger`, но в данном случае поток просто запускает метод другого класса, ссылку на который имеет.