# как передать в метод main как аргументы путь к файлам которые были выделены (в виндовс-> в папке-> мышю) и запушены(ENTER) моей программой по дефолту

Tags: java, javafx

надо что бы программа принимала как аргументы файлы с расширением .mp3(точнее пути к ним (C://music//a.mp3 , C://music//b.mp3 ,....)) когда я ее запускаю

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 // как назначить аргументами например путь к файлам с расширением .mp3
}
```

надо чтобы каждый выбранный файл не запускал свой собственный метод main и передавался как один аргумент а все файлы передавались в один main

Comment: вам как args[0],args[1] приходит то, что вы передаете при запуске программы. По умолчанию, если у вас программа правильная и все пути в Path прописаны правильно, то если вы ваши файлы выделите и перетащите на ваш *.java то у вас 1 из файлов должнен будет передаться как параметр, насколько я помню. А вот, что с ними делать, это вам надо реализоввывать внутри `main`

Comment: @Armen, у вас в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/Открытие-нескольких-файлов-из-проводника-в-одном-экземпляре-приложения почти готовый ответ есть на этот вопрос. Проще не получится. Уточняйте у ИмяФамилия, если что-то не понятно.

Comment: @insolor привет то есть тот ответ с сокетом решает маю проблему?)просто я не смог разобрался  но если это и есть ответ пойду поглубже изучу

Comment: Да, через сокет

Comment: @insolor тот ответ к сожалению не помог ИмяФамилия видоизменил ответ под мой код чтобы помочь но это не сработало если ты был уверен что этот кусочек кода решил бы маю проблему глянь  на нее может заметишь что не так